# Pythonic get element of array or default if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, list, element, default

We have

```
matches = re.findall(r'somewhat', 'somewhere')
```

Can we simplify this

```
if len(matches) > index:
    return matches[index]
else:
    return 'default'
```

or

```
return matches[index] if len(mathes) > index else 'default'
```

to something similar to JS's

```
return matches[index] || 'default'
```

that we can simply use

```
return 'somewhere'.match(/somewhat/)[index] || 'default'
```

Comment: That JavaScript solution doesn't work in all cases (e.g. when `mathes[index]==0`).

Comment: Agree. Not in all, but in most practical cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
>>> reg = re.compile('-\d+-')
>>> reg.findall('a-23-b-12-c') or ['default']
['-23-', '-12-']
>>> reg.findall('a-b-c') or ['default']
['default']
```

Edit

Ugly one-liner

```
(reg.findall('a-b-c')[index:] or ['default'])[0]
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know that empty arrays are considered False. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use a try except block. You'd be required to consider when index was negative though. Is this an error or an acceptable input?

But the following would work:

```
try:
    return re.findall(r'somewhat', 'somewhere')[index]
except IndexError:
    return 'default'
```

This is meant to be the preferred way if you're concerned about efficiency as it avoids checking the bounds of the array twice (once when you manually do it and and second when python does its internal check as well).

edit: I've never particularly liked this way as it hides any IndexErrors thrown by sub calls  and would return the default (which I doubt would be the desired behaviour and a possible source of bugs).

Comment: I believe that using `try-except`s is less efficient than checking array length (even twice)

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. I think I drew a false analogy from dicts where try/except is better than d.has_key(k)/d[k].

Comment: I ran I few tests. The answer depends on what you think is the most likely outcome. When the index is present the try/except block is twice as fast as checking for the list's bounds. When it isn't present the try/except block is 5 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, because running `mathes[x]` with an invalid index will throw an `IndexError`, which does not return `False`.